# Scotty and POST params

Tags: haskell, post, scotty

I'm having an issue with the Scotty web server right now - `rescue` isn't working for unfound parameters - I'm still getting a 404 with the following code:

```
post "/newsletter/create" ( do
  (param "subscriber[email]") `rescue` (\msg -> text msg)
  formContent <- param "subscriber[email]"
  text $ "found! " ++ show formContent )
```

I can see that when I just use `params` instead, my data is there, and indexed with "`subscriber[email]`". Is there something going on with `[` escaping? Any help with this would be tremendous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some cleanup I got it to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  post "/newsletter/create" $ do
    formContent <- (param "subscriber[email]") `rescue` (\msg -> return msg)
    text $ "found! " `TL.append` formContent
```

I made a bunch of modifications, but the key point was that `rescue` is used as a wrapper around `param`, not to change any internal state, hence you shouldn't call it twice.  The square brackets didn't cause me any trouble.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Derp. Thank you. I'm wondering if `param_` or `params_` non-destructive functions would be a good idea...

Comment: I just found out something that really sucks with Scotty - if you rescue from a parameter, you can't actually use the parameter:

`rescue :: ActionM a -> (Text -> ActionM a) -> ActionM a`

If your handlers are `ActionM ()`, then you can't pull the parameter because it's type will be `()`, and not `Text` :(

Comment: `get` itself forces the Unit type :/